# How to make search engine to run fast

Tags: html, drupal, mysql

We designed a search engine but it takes much time to execute its query in drupal.We have uploaded many modules in our search engine.So could you please guide what will be the remedy for make our search engine fast.Is there any thing that i can do with my site? Thanks In Advance

Comment: Are you expecting someone will post magic option "do_fast_query = On" to use it in my.cnf?

Comment: @zerkms Are you saying Drupal doesn't have the `dont_suck` flag? That's disappointing indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question, I can't seem to understand whether you have totally made your own search engine or customized a pre-existing search engine. In general it is a **very bad** idea to make your own search engine. Building a good search engine is a complicated affair. It takes years and a large team of talented programmers. No wonder you're running into problems. Why are your re-inventing the wheel?? Its a good idea to use a pre-existing search engine like lucence, apache solr, sphinx etc. and customize it for your specific needs.

Also if you're facing performance constraints how can anybody know what the problem is from your question. Who knows what code you've written and what the bottlenecks are there?

BTW if you use **normal Drupal search** they recommend that you should **not** use it if your system has more than ~5000 Nodes. Default Drupal search simply places too much load on the MySQL database when you have lots of nodes. If your search engine works similarly in *concept* to default Drupal search check the number of nodes on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Try sphinx. You can use it like any other mysql engine.
http://www.sphinxsearch.com/